# Multivariable definition of continuity in Buck Advanced Calc.

Tags: real-analysis

I was working through Buck's Advanced Calculus and found his definition of continuity strange compared to the definition in Rudin's PMA.

I thought his definition was useful, but is it wrong when compared to the definition in baby Rudin? I realize Rudin is working in metric spaces, and was hoping to quickly go through Buck and do baby Rudin. I've read, "you should have the definitions down cold."

Below is a copy of Buck's definition. It isn't the usual $\varepsilon$ - $\delta$ definition, per se.

D is a region in the plane.

> *Definition 1:* A numerical-valued function $f$, deﬁned on a set $D$, is said to be continuous at a point $p_o \in D$ if, given any number $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a neighborhood $U$ about $p_o$ such that $\vert f (p)- f (p_o)\vert\lt \varepsilon$ for every point $p\in U \cap D $. The function $f$ is said to be continuous on $D$ if it is continuous at each point of $D$.

Comment: It might help to copy down Baby Rudin's definition of continuity for those who don't have the book handy.

Comment: They're equivalent in any metric space (assuming the topology being considered is induced by the metric), because saying $|p-p_0| < \delta$ is the same as defining a neighbourhood $U$ about $p_0$, and conversely, for any neighbourhood $U$, you can find an open ball inside it to give you a $\delta$

Comment: The comments and answer already here at the time of this comment are correct, so I won't add anything in that regard, but as a tangent I would recommend adding Mathematical Analysis by Tom Apostol to the mix if you can get your hands on a copy of it. The book is more streamlined toward Analysis than Buck and is a lighter, more interrelated mix of the two (closely related) subjects of advanced calculus and beginning analysis - for example, p. 78 of this volume actually gives both of these methods side-by-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are synonym. Here's 
Rudin's definition quoted, and compared to Buck's definition

> Suppose $X, Y$ are metric spaces, $E \subset X$, $p \in E$ and $f$ maps $E$ into $Y$...

Take $X = \mathbb{R}^2, Y = \mathbb{R}$ with usual Euclidean metric $d_X(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) = \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2}$, $d_Y(x,y) = |x-y|$, and denote $E$ by $D$, and so $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$

> ... Then $f$ is said to be continuous at $p$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $d_Y(f(x), f(p))>\epsilon$ for all points $x \in E$ for which $d_X(x,p) < \delta$

Said another way, $f$ *is continuous at $p_0 = p \in D$* if, given $\epsilon > 0$, there is *a neighborhood $U$ about $p_0$* (i.e. a set of points $x$ such that $d_X(x,p) < \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$, see page 32 for def. in Rudin) satisfying $d_Y(f(x), f(p_0)) = |f(x) - f(p_0)| < \epsilon$ for every points  $x \in D$ (where $f$ is defined), but for which $d_X(x, p_0) < \delta$ (i.e. $x \in U$ the neighborhood about $p_0$) hence the intersection $x \in U \cap D$ in Buck's definition.

Comment: I guess my issue arose when the  author a paragraph before the definition says "D is a region in the plane" and then I guess says D is something different in the definition, as you're saying D is the domain.

Comment: @user221227 ah, you're right. But it seems Buck never defines *region* except to mean loosely a subset of $R^2$. But still is compatible with Rudin, with $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ under the usual metric.

Comment: What do you think of Buck's treatment of differential forms? I guess after working that far into his book do you think his treatment is sufficient to say one understands them?

Comment: @user221227 I don't know. Perhaps a better question "is it enough to prepare you for a serious differential geometry course?" maybe not, but certainly getting this far into the book will make Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds and Tu's Intro to Manifolds, among others, much more accessible. Good luck.